# Delete until the right end of the current inner block

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions

Let's say that I have a code like this (*`|` represents the cursor position*):

```
func1(x|, func2(), y);
```

I would like to get:

```
func1(x|);
```

Is there a way to *delete the code from the position of the cursor to the position preceding the right end of the current inner block*?

I know that I can go with `dt).` but I wonder if there is a way to mix it with what `di)` does.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing if there's an easy way to "delete the left/right half of inner/outter block", as you asked. But as a side note, I would probably do `C);` in this particular case.

Comment: Sometimes the `%` motion can do what you're looking for (i.e. `d%`).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I would use

```
d])
```

which means delete (`d`) to the next unmatched ')' (`])`).

See [`:help ])`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%5D%29).

Comment: How would you do this if you were inside a string.  For example when I try `function( bob, "a | string", otherParams)` hitting `d])` with the cursor at `|` does nothing (sends a bell code)

Answer (score 5):

Motions go *only* in one direction while text-objects go *only* in two directions.

This means that you can't have half of a text-object unless you create a custom operator pending motion that uses that text-object under the hood or mimics its behavior.

In your example, the text covered by `i)` is pretty easy to visualize:

```
func1(x, func2(), y);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but how would you tell Vim to operate from the cursor to the end of that text? One would need to create custom operators like `obi)` and `oei)` (semi-random examples).

```
" ()
onoremap oei) :normal! vi)o``<CR>
onoremap obi) :normal! vi)``<CR>

" []
onoremap oei] :normal! vi]o``<CR>
onoremap obi] :normal! vi]``<CR>

" {}
onoremap oei} :normal! vi}o``<CR>
onoremap obi} :normal! vi}``<CR>

" ""
onoremap oei" :normal! vi"o``<CR>
onoremap obi" :normal! vi"``<CR>

" ''
onoremap oei" :normal! vi'o``<CR>
onoremap obi" :normal! vi'``<CR>
```

Comment: Would be interesting to create a generic motion that re-uses all already defined text-objects, combined with the current cursor position; for example,  instead of `ib`, `imb` to the right and `iMb` to the left, and so on (automatically).

Answer (score 4):

For this specific case I would `dfy`

For the general case:

- `dT(` delete from the cursor to the start of the block
- `vib` select the rest of the inner block
- `p`  replace the inner block with what you just deleted

You could make it into a mapping.

```
 :map K dt(vibp
```

Answer (score 3):

The other existing answers are all dependent on vim's definition and detection of a block. My strategy for this kind of deletions is to use the `c` command combined with with the `f` motion and the actual character to stop at. This will then actually delete the stop character, but since it also was the last key you pressed repeating it twice has next to zero cost, and that will insert it again since `c` changes to insert mode.

---

To explain with examples, for

```
func1(x|, func2(), y);
```

the command `c2f))` will give

```
func1(x)|;
```

which might at first seem less elegant than some of the other answers, however notice that this strategy is **universal** and does not depend on any block definition.

---

For instance with

```
<div| class="some-class">text</div>
```

the command `cf>>` will give

```
<div>|text</div>
```

---

Or when editing csv files like

```
2016-11-29,question,vi|.stackexchange.com,10435
```

the command `cf,,` will give

```
2016-11-29,question,vi,|10435
```

---

Often I use this to delete the rest of a string, from

```
printf("Hello world| - a boring example\n");
```

to

```
printf("Hello world\|n");
```

with `cf\\`

or from

```
print("Hello world| - a boring example");
```

to

```
print("Hello world"|);
```

with `cf""`.

---

This does change the current position to a slightly different place than asked for, and also changes into insert mode. But I wanted to share my go-to-solution for deleting the rest of anything.

Comment: The problem with `cf` solution is that I have to specify the character where I want to stop deleting. The questions asks what to do if you cannot simply do `cf)` because there's another `)` before the `)` you actually want to reach (for example when you want to change `func(x|, g(x, x), x, x, g(x, x))` to `func(x)`). Basically, I wanted to know if I can avoid pressing `.` after `cf)`.

Comment: Note that you can also use `t` instead of `f` to delete up to but not including the given character, so for your first example (`func1(x|, func2(), y);`), you could just use `d2t)`.

As @MateuszPiotrowski mentions though, it's not a general solution and requires you to know which character you want to delete to. As you generally know which character ends the block you're in for a given language though, that's not so bad.

Answer (score 3):

The [vim-ninja-feet](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-ninja-feet) plugin might be what you're looking for. From what I understand, it makes `d[` and `d]` into "delete from cursor to start/end of text object", so `d]i)` should be "delete until end of surrounding parentheses".