# Move to end of current inner paren/block

Tags: cursor-motions

Let's say we have this little snippet here open, and the cursor is at the `|`:

```rs
some_function(a[0], | some_other_function(a[1]));
```

How would you best delete, change, or visually select the `some_other_function(a[1])` part? Usually, I'd do something like `d2t)`, but that requires manually counting the parentheses or brackets or whatever else you're trying to count. What would you do for...

```rs
A(B( | C(D(E(F(G(H(I(J())))))))))
```

Yeah, it's a silly example, but it explains the issue well, I guess. The only alternative I can think of would be `di)` but then it would delete stuff before the cursor as well, and you'd have to retype all of those things.

Is there some built-in way that Vim can just delete until it reaches the end of whatever grouping it's currently inside? ("delete until you hit the current block/parentheses's end" or something like that)

Something like it just having a counter starting at 1 and just select forward, incrementing each time it sees an "opening" character and then decrementing for each "closing" character, stopping when the counter hits 0.

Sorry if this is a dupe. Couldn't find anything relevant, but I probably just suck at phrasing this problem into "searchable" keywords.

Comment: nvm finally found the correct thread: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10435/47759

Comment: For your original I would use `d%`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble oh, thanks. I was just gonna do `d])` cuz I thought `%` meant the whole file... TIL

Comment: There’s a difference between the % motion (normal mode) and the % range (Ex commands after :)